# When i use draggable for an element then the click function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I am using the draggable function for the element using jquery..when I use this the click function is not working on that..why is that and how to remove this bug? pls help me

```
// Reizable and draggable for the YOUTUBE widget**************
$(function() {
    $( "#youtube" ).draggable(
        {cursor: 'move'}
    );

    $( "#youtube" ).resizable({
        ghost: true,
        alsoResize: '#player',
        handles: "n, e, s, w"
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'click function is not working'? Are you trying to bind a function to the click handler? If so could you post that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably because the click event requires the mouse to go down and up. if you're dragging, that never fires. Try using the mousedown event instead.